# How to set dynamically isIgnorePagination in jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a jasper file which i export to PDF and Excel as of now i am using only one jasper i want the PDF exported report  should be "isIgnorePagination=''true" and for Excel report should be "isIgnorePagination = 'false' "?

How to set from java code?

Comment: You can pass this property via JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION parameter (in case you use JasperFillManager.fillReport method)

Comment: Hi Alex, What i want exactly is how to set "isIgnorePagination = 'true'" for PDF and "isIgnorePagination = 'false'" for excel?

Comment: From java code you can set JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION and set export format as you wish

Answer (score 7):

You will need to know at runtime if you are exporting to Excel or PDF, which you should know.

Just as an example:

```
public void generateReport(JasperPrint report, boolean isExcel, String saveTo){
  JRExporter exporter = null;
  if (isExcel) {
    exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
    //we set the one page per sheet parameter here
    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.TRUE);
  } else {
    exporter = new JRPdfExporter();     
  }
  exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);124
  exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, saveTo);
  export.exportReport();
}
```

Comment: JRXlsExporter.setParameter has been deprecated since this answer has been written - use the solution of "Anthony O." now - that is: `fillingParameters.put(JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION, Boolean.TRUE);` and `final JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, fillingParameters, dataSource);`

Comment: You could also use `SimpleXlsReportConfiguration configuration = new net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleXlsReportConfiguration();`
and then do `configuration.setOnePagePerSheet(false);`
and `exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);`

Answer (score 6):

According to [JasperReports sample reference](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/nopagebreak/):

> For various purposes this flag [`isIgnorePagination` in jrxml] can be overriden at report **filling time** using the optional built-in [`IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRParameter.html#IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION) parameter.

So the code should be something like this:

```java
final Map<String, Object> fillingParameters = new HashMap<>();
if (exportType == ExportType.XLS) {
    fillingParameters.put(JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION, Boolean.TRUE);
}
final JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, fillingParameters, dataSource);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found solution for this.

my code is:

```
paramaters.put("fromDate", fromDate);
paramaters.put("toDate", toDate);
if (!output.equals("pdf"))
{
    paramaters.put("IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION", true);
}
else
    paramaters.put("IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION", false);

JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(CompiledReport,paramaters, connection);

if (output.equals("html")) {
    generateHtmlResponse(response, jasperPrint);
} else if (output.equals("pdf")) {
    generatePdfResponse(response, jasperPrint);
} else if(output.equals("excel")) {
    generateXLResponse(response, jasperPrint);
}
```